# How to prove the following relation of Conditional Value-at-Risk and Value-at-Risk?

Tags: value-at-risk, cvar

How to prove the following relation of Conditional Value-at-Risk $\text{CVaR}_{\alpha}(X)$ and Value-at-Risk $\text{VaR}_{\alpha}(X)$,
\begin{equation}
\text{CVaR}_{\alpha}(X) = \text{VaR}_{\alpha}(X)+\frac{1}{\alpha}E[(X-\text{VaR}_{\alpha}(X))^{+}]?
\end{equation}
Here are the definations of Value-at-Risk and Conditional Value-at-Risk.

Value-at-Risk

Suppose $X$ is a random variable, the value-at-risk (VaR) of $X$ at a confidence level $1-\alpha$ where $0<\alpha<1$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
\text{VaR}_{\alpha}(X) := \inf\left\{x :Pr\{X>x\}\leq\alpha\right\}.
\end{equation}

Conditional Value-at-Risk

Based on the definition of Value-at-Risk, the Donditional Value-at-Risk (CVaR) of $X$ at a confidence level $1-\alpha$ (namely, significance level $\alpha$) is defined to be
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{CVaR}_{\alpha}(X) = \frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{0}^{\alpha}\mathrm{VaR}_{s}(X)ds.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly different take here:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let $F$ be the cumulative distribution function of $X$. We assume that $F$ is continuous. Then, for $x\ge 0$, 
\begin{align*}
F^{-1}(x) = \inf\{s: F(s) \ge x \}.
\end{align*}
Moreover,
\begin{align*}
\text{VaR}_{\alpha}(X) &= \inf\left\{x :1-F(x) \le \alpha\right\}\\
&=F^{-1}(1-\alpha).
\end{align*}
Consequently
\begin{align*}
E\Big(\big(X-\text{VaR}_{\alpha}(X)\big)^+\Big) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Big(x-\text{VaR}_{\alpha}(X)\Big)^+ dF(x)\\
&=\int_{\text{VaR}_{\alpha}(X)}^{\infty} \Big(x-\text{VaR}_{\alpha}(X)\Big) dF(x)\\
&=\int_{1-\alpha}^1 \Big(F^{-1}(y)-\text{VaR}_{\alpha}(X)\Big) dy\\
&=\int_{1-\alpha}^1 F^{-1}(y) dy - \alpha \text{VaR}_{\alpha}(X) \\
&=\int_{1-\alpha}^1 \text{VaR}_{1-y}(X) dy - \alpha \text{VaR}_{\alpha}(X) \\
&=\int_0^{\alpha} \text{VaR}_{s}(X) ds - \alpha \text{VaR}_{\alpha}(X).
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
\text{VaR}_{\alpha}(X)+\frac{1}{\alpha}E\Big(\big(X-\text{VaR}_{\alpha}(X)\big)^+\Big) &= \frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{0}^{\alpha}\text{VaR}_{s}(X)ds.
\end{align*}